# NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: contains in other NSArray with custom key path

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have 2 `NSArrays` with each containing custom `objects`:

- `NSArrayToFilter`
- `NSArrayUsedForFiltering`

I want to filter my first `array` with a `predicate` that uses my second `array`. I want to return all the custom `objects` from my `NSArrayToFilter` where an attribute is not available in an other attribute from the custom `objects` in my `NSArrayUsedForFiltering`.

This is some **pseudo-code** for what I want to achieve:

```
[NSArrayToFilter filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT self.attribute IN %@.attribute", NSArrayUsedForFiltering]
```

Comment: You want to get common objects from both array ?

Comment: I want to get the objects from the first array but based on a predicate that uses an attribute from the second array objects.